# Is SonarQube the only open source SAST tool

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, cicd, sast

I want to implement SAST on our CICD pipeline and I can't find opensource SAST tools except sonarqube. Is there any alternative tools to sonarqube?

I just want to explore other tools but can't find any opensource tools..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only SAST scanners which are open source and support multiple languages are Semgrep and SonarQube (as opposed to eslint, Spotbugs, etc. which are typically language-specific and usually more focused on linting than security issues):

- https://github.com/semgrep/semgrep is LGPL-2.1 and supports about ~37 languages https://semgrep.dev/docs/supported-languages/
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube is LGPL 3.0.1 and supports ~34 languages https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/languages/overview/

Answer (score -1):

Sonarqube is not the only tool. However it is the most known / market leader so to speak. Other tools are e.g. [Spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) (previsouly known as findbugs), [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) and so on. You can check this [list on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java)